# What is the difference between PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea and PlaceHolderPageTitle?

Tags: page-layout

Why do we have **PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea** and **PlaceHolderPageTitle** in master page.

What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only difference would be where your master page places them.
Out of box master pages usually have the **PlaceHolderPageTitle** in the head section - title tag.

```
<head>
   <title><asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server"/></title>
</head>
```

**PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea** is instead used in the title table, so it is inside the actual page body.

```
<table class="s4-titletable" cellspacing="0">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td class="s4-titlelogo">....</td>
         <td class="s4-titletext">
            ...
            <h2>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server" />
            </h2>
            <div class="s4-pagedescription" tabindex="0" >
               <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageDescription" runat="server"/>
            </div>
            ...
        </td>
        ....
     </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```